# Retrofit post request with parameters

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using postman extension for post request. I want to make same request with android. I used retrofit library for access my goal. But I can't get successful result. Where is my mistake in code ?

Postman : 
[image]

My interface :

```
public interface Interfacem {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/login")
    Call<ResponseBody> getResponse(@Field("signin[username]") String username,@Field("signin[password]")String password );
}
```

and retrofit usage :

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl("http://myurl.com")
                        .build();

                Interfacem service = retrofit.create(Interfacem.class);
                Call<ResponseBody> result =service.getResponse("myUsername","myPassword");
                result.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println(response.body().string().toString());
                        } catch (IOException|NullPointerException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this
provide body

```
public class SignBody {
  @SerializedName("signin[username]") @Expose private String username;
  @SerializedName("signin[password]") @Expose private String password;
}
```

change interface to

```
@POST("/login")
    Call<ResponseBody> getResponse(@Body SignBody body);
```

Comment: I get this message : "Required fields can not be empty"

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `Retrofit 2.x`, Try to change your build of Retrofit object as below :

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl("http://myurl.com/")
                        .build();
```

maybe the things below will help

**the leading** `/` within the partial url overrides the end of API endpoint definition. Removing the `/` from the partial url and adding it to the base url will bring the expected result.

Example:

**The API interface**

```
    public interface UserService {  
    @POST("/me")
    Call<User> me();}
```

**Build `Retrofit` with `baseUrl`**

```
    Retrofit retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()  
    .baseUrl("https://your.api.url/v2");
    .build();
```

**Then Call :**

```
UserService service = retrofit.create(UserService.class);
```

**-->**  The request Url will be `https://your.api.url/me` (`/v2` has been disapear)

**PRO TIP**

> use relative urls for your partial endpoint urls and end your
>   base url with the trailing slash `/`.

**Interface**

```
public interface UserService {  
    @POST("me")
    Call<User>me();
}
```

**Retrofit with baseURL**

```
Retrofit retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()  
    .baseUrl("https://your.api.url/v2/");
    .build();
```

**Call**

```
UserService service = retrofit.create(UserService.class);
```

**-->** The request URL will be `https://your.api.url/v2/me`

Answer (score 0):

Which version you use in retrofit? Below code for version 2.0. If any Header require please check. If you can share url and username or password. I will check.

```
public interface Interfacem {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("login")
    Call<ResponseBody> getResponse(@Field("username") String username,@Field("password")String password );
}


Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl("http://myurl.com/")
                        .build();

                Interfacem service = retrofit.create(Interfacem.class);
                Call<ResponseBody> result =service.getResponse("myUsername","myPassword");
                result.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println(response.body().string().toString());
                        } catch (IOException|NullPointerException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: What is ResponseBody? is this custom class or from retrofit?